# Make elements in array equal by adding adjacent elements

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I need help in solving this program.

Program statement:
You are provided with an array of n integers. You have to make all elements in array same.the only way to do that is by adding adjacent elements in the array.
A single addition of two elements counts as a step.calculate the min steps required to solve.

```
Ex 1: arr = [2,2,4,1,3]
       Step 1: 2+2 = 4
       Step 2: 1+3 = 4
      arr = [4,4,4]
  So the final answer would be 2.

Ex 2: arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
       Step 1: 1+2 = 3
       Step 2: 3+4 = 7
      arr = [3,7,5]
       Step 3: 3+7 = 10
      arr = [10,5]
       Step 4: 10+5 = 15
      arr = [15]
```

In the last step the array element is reduced to single element and is considered to be same.
So the answer would be 4 steps.

I would be glad if someone could come up with a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I tried several approaches but I could never bring myself to code without a solid approach to the problem. So if you had any approach to a solution, kindly share it.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, just tell us about one or two of the approaches you tried. In the meantime I'll post a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint. In the end, all of the elements must have the same value. What do you know about that value? And could you solve the puzzle if you knew the value?

Is that enough to go on?

**EDIT:** Divide the problem into two simpler problems. (This is a *very* useful general technique.)

First, look at the initial list of numbers, and try to make some deductions about what the final value can and cannot be. For example:

```
9 1 16 7 10 9 12 14 4 21 1 24 2
```

What could the final value be?

Second, if you were told the final value, how would you solve the puzzle?

Comment: The value could be any number. and if the final number is known then it makes things easier.